# Login attempt restriction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using membership tag for login attempt restriction after 3 times given wrong password in `web.config` file. But it is not working please help me
this is my `web.config` file below code is I given but it is not working

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="mydb" connectionString="Data Source=mydbcnt;Initial Catalog=19052015;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" ></add>
</connectionStrings>


<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
         <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it is not working'? You can never login, you can login even after 3 failed attempts, your application does not run....?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<clear/>` tag before adding your provider.

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" [...]/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

As stated [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/common-gotcha-don-t-forget-to-clear-when-adding-providers), the  section within the `web.config` file is implemented as a collection, and so it is possible to register multiple providers at the same time, includig the ones created by ASP.NET in the root `web.config` file on your machine.

Comment: <membership>

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security"
            connectionStringName="Grevence"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
            passwordAttemptWindow="10"
            applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>

    </membership>

Comment: this is my page membership tag but it is not working. I don't know how to connect membership tag to my login page. exactly what i want is user enter wrong enter password 3 times user account disabled how it will do please help me...